# How to add Terraform based software to IBM Cloud's private catalog?

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-schematics, terraform-provider-ibm

I use IBM Cloud Schematics to generate and then apply a plan to create resources in IBM Cloud. Terraform templates are present in github repository and the URL of the same is provided in IBM Cloud Schematics' workspace. How shall I make this available as a software in private catalog of IBM Cloud for users to consume?

Comment: Do you mean something like documented here? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-create-private-catalog Adding your own software to a private catalog

Comment: yes, that's right, wanted similar documentation for adding terraform based software.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Terraform-based [software to your private catalog on IBM Cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-create-private-catalog). The software is named **product**. Its definition can be provided in a compressed tape archive file (tgz) or via a Git repository. The setup, including initial validation, is performed using Schematics and Schematics workspaces. See "[Creating Terraform templates](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/schematics?topic=schematics-create-tf-config)" in the IBM Cloud Schematics docs for details.

What worked for me is to have a **main.tf**, **provider.tf** and **variables.tf**. Then I bundled them up as **myproduct.tgz** and added them to my private catalog either via the UI (IBM Cloud Console) or the [CLI for catalog management](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-manage-catalogs-plugin). Thereafter, the product needs to be validated, then published to the catalog.

Users can see the product in the configured catalog category. When deployed, it creates the resources and a Schematics workspace. When deleting the workspace, the product and its resources are removed. This works for me even for special stuff like IAM access groups.